# (Objective-C) Open view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, view, push

In my project, I have a Table View Controller with class *`NieuwsViewController`*.
I want this VC to be opened when the app is opened through a push message.

I assume this has to be done in AppDelegate.m in '*application `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`*' or '*`didReceiveRemoteNotification`*', but then what?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this](http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html) to handle URL scheme.

You need to instantiate your `UIViewController` in `handleOpenURL` (with `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` if you use storyboard for example) and then you will be able to present it (or to push it depending what you want).

Comment: That seems quite interesting... Thanks for the url, I'll have a look at it!